# Java Out of Memory Exception While Reading Database

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-sqlite

I am trying to retrieve data from a database. However, while reading, my cursor threw a Java Out of Memory Exception. Looking at the stack trace, it had to do with a string builder. I thought that moving the code to a thread would work, but I still had the exception. Here is the code that is not working:

```
 public Object[] getData() {
    CustomRunnable runnable = new CustomRunnable();
    Thread runThread = new Thread(runnable);
    runThread.start();
    while ((runThread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED)) {
    }
    return runnable.getDBlist().toArray();
}

public class CustomRunnable implements Runnable {

    List<String> dbList;
    public boolean done = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        dbList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS + " WHERE 1";
        //Cursor code
        Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        String dbString = "";
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMNAME)) != null) {
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMNAME));
            }
        /*
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_COST))!=null){
            dbString+=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_COST));
        }
        */
            dbList.add(dbString);
        }
        c.close();
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        done = true;
    }

    public List<String> getDBlist() {
        return dbList;
    }
}
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 83410 byte allocation with 71348 free bytes and 69KB until OOM
                                                                    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
                                                                    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)
                                                                    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
                                                                    at com.daita.ereciept.DBHandler.getData(DBHandler.java:62)
                                                                    at com.daita.ereciept.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:37)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: The obvious first: if you're using a memory-based SQLite database, that may be the cause of your memory overflow.

Comment: The a-bit-less obvious then: I have no evidence for that, but, if the SQLiteDatabase stores the result of its queries in memory, and your query has a huge result set (which may be the case, since you're handling 40K characters long strings), then the result set itself may be engulfing your memory. Try making multiple queries with a LIMIT clause, to only fetch 10/100/1000 rows at a time.

Comment: Your concatenating strings using `+=` where is the `StringBuilder`?

Comment: The StringBuilder is part of the Cursor that is reading the database. @Enzokie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to troubleshoot your JVM heap size as first option. If you are sure you are not wrong.

By wrong I mean... You know it's not much data to cause oom. And you need this much data in memory.

Comment: I have set android:largeHeap to be true, and the heap space is increasing, but that is not enough to get the database working. @gaurava

Comment: Next thing to choose a garbage collection strategy to choose your demand

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the garbage collection strategy? Some code would help a lot. @gaurava

Comment: Garbage collection is a setting like you did for heap.

Comment: System.gc() is not working for me. It still shows the OOM. @gaurava